# Flyway migration with existing database using hasura - PostgresSQL Backup

Tags: database, postgresql, backup, flyway, hasura

I've develop a web platform that uses a PostgresSQL database along with Hasura to make GraphQL interface. This platform was deployed on a Google Cloud enviroment: the database is running in a Google Cloud SQL instance, the Hasura and a simple node.js servers are running on Cloud Run instances.

Anyway, since the database should keep growing, I need a secure and reliable way to keep track of changes done in development env to futher deploy it to production database.

The buck of the edits to the database schema are done using the Hasura Console and by now I just need a solution to track changes in data schema made in development enviroment to deploy only the needed changes to production

Reading about migrations I've found out Flyway as a solution to keep of these changes. However, there still some concerns about the implementation of Flyway in the project. But a couple of question arrise:

- Is it possible to use the PostgresSQL (pgAdmin) backup generated files as migrations?
- How could I make a migration from a development to the production database? Just by adding the remote url from Google Cloud SQL the do the migration?

There's no much need to keep track of changes of the data in production.

Is there a better option to control changes between development and production databases?

If a make frequent schema backup (using pgAdmin Backup tool) and run restore on the production database, it would do what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Is it possible to use the PostgresSQL (pgAdmin) backup generated files as migrations?

I think you are going the wrong way. Flyway is about the migration scripts you execute to propogate DB version. The backup file contains the whole database. If you want to replace the whole database with the new version of it you may simply drop the old one and create the new one, but you will loose data that way. You can of course use flyway to restore the backup for you, but that way you'll get only the version table. If you'll update over several versions, then multiple restores will be performed that is not needed.

2. How could I make a migration from a development to the production database? Just by adding the remote url from Google Cloud SQL the do the migration?

I tried google'ing (entered "Google Cloud SQL flyway") and the first result pointed me to Umberto D'Ovido post [Setup Flyway with Google Cloud SQL](https://umberto.xyz/post/2021-03-20-flyway-cloud-sql/) I'm sure with a little effor you'll find the instructions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to do changes in my local dev database (via Hasura Console or pgAdmin interface) and once done restore the schema to the production database, but restore only the changes that I made, is that possible with or without flyway? eg: I create a new collumn in a table on local database, when I want deploy to production the restore only adds that one column without affect the data

Comment: About backups: of course you are correct that they could not be used as migrations directly but backups are needed to create environment to develop and test migrations. We prepare environment with 2 databases: production version and release version. Migrations (in our case) are set of scripts that migratie DB of production version to release version.

Comment: @rafaeelneto , to my knowledge flyway won't be enough. There are tools for comparing 2 databases and generating diff scripts. I know MicroOlap has something, DBeaver also has migration building. Anyway I don't suggest using them, because you loose the control over the changes you make.  Also, migration involves changing not only schema, data too - I'm not sure if its possible to make data diffs (from the tables you need). I'd encourage you to make your own scripts (just copy generated by pgAdmin) for every object you change and feed them to flyway.

Comment: @Alex Yu, You may use a backup as a "seed" for your database and then run the update scripts till the version you need to test/deploy. Backup may be done in form of SQL statements, so there is no problem using it as the initial version. 
In our company to speed things up we have "template" database that was created using scripts. When we need a new one for testing we `create database dbname template template_db_name`  and then migration scripts on it. It reduces creation time greatly (compared to backup/restore for  large DB).

Comment: Thank you for helping me. Following your tips i'm testing flyway inside my workflow to see how i could do what i want possible. Anyways, i think that the better way is to follow the tips from @JuliusTuskenis by making my own scripts and feed flyway. But testing the flyway i found that by doing a backup only of the schema of db as plain sql can be used as a baseline on flyway